# Use same format as <input type="date">

Tags: javascript

I have 2 inputs in my page, one that is type text, and one that is type date. The input type date as a specific format (the date shown on the input, not the value in the code). I want to use that same format for my input type text across all browsers and all OS. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: maybe you can find some useful answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Mask plugin to do that.

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/